# Reduce with BiFunction only

Tags: java-8, reduce

Traditional functional language think of reduce in term of initial value and accumulator over the list. In Java things are more complicate as it require a BinaryOperator.

I would like to know if we have a better way of writing this kind of function:

```
public JsonObject growPath(final JsonObject obj) {
    // paths is a list of string
    return this.paths.stream().reduce(obj, (child, path) -> {
        if (!child.containsKey(path) || !(child.get(path) instanceof JsonObject)) {
            // We do override anything that is not an object since the path
            // specify that it should be an object.
            child.put(path, JsonObject.create());
        }
        return child.getObject(path);
    } , (first, last) -> {
        return last;
    });
}
```

I would like to avoid the BinaryOperator argument. Should I use something different than reduce ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you know what this `BinaryOperator` argument is for and why it's there (see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808485/purpose-of-third-argument-to-reduce-function-in-java-8-functional-programming)?

Comment: If you are modifying the argument, you should not use `reduce`, but `collect`. Since this also doesn’t work like you intend, your task isn’t appropriate for a Stream operation at all.

Comment: @Tunaki I want the same reduce than in clojure,lisp, scheme, haskell, smalltalk, ... aka foldl/foldr, BinaryOperator is not a reduction as it accept only one type `U acc(U,U)`. A proper reduction function is `U acc(U,T)`.

Comment: @mathk Yes, and look at the linked question, this argument is used for parallel computation. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880331/passing-a-collection-using-a-reduce-3-parameters-function-streams-java-8 also. `reduce` is most likely not what you want here.

Comment: @Tunaki Actually I am not even thinking of parallel computation.Fine if that  could be used for parallel computation but it is not what I am looking for. I am just looking into a more functional way of processing list. I though that stream could be the way to achieve that but it looks not to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. You are performing an action that modifies `obj`, which has nothing to do with reduction at all. If we ignore the modifying aspect, this operation is a left-fold, which Streams do not support (in general). You can only implement it using `reduce`, if the function is associative, which your function is not. So you best implement it without Streams:

```
public JsonObject growPath(JsonObject obj) {
    for(String path: this.paths)
        obj = (JsonObject)obj.compute(path,
            (key,child)->child instanceof JsonObject? child: JsonObject.create());
    return obj;
}
```